# mix `select` query results by certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I "mix" `select` query results by certain column?

I have the following query:
`SELECT * FROM list WHERE server='1' ORDER BY important DESC, id ASC`

the above can give me:

```
1. type1
2. type1
3. type1
4. type1
5. type2
6. type2
7. type2
8. type1
9. type2
10. type1
```

each row has a `type` column, What I would like to do is to mix the results so that the
query will take into account the `ORDER BY important DESC, id AS` but also "mix" the result by `type` column

for example:

```
1. type1
5. type2
2. type1
6. type2
3. type1
7. type2
4. type1
9. type2
8. type1
10. type1
```

what I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE server='1' ORDER BY important DESC, id ASC, RAND(type)
```

Comment: Mix them?  Are you saying that if there are several records with the same `important` and `id` values you would like them to display within the same range but in a random order each time the query is ran?  What is returned when you run your current query that users `RAND`?

Comment: Also, can you include a sample of the data you are querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting by `id` after `important`, so the randomness never takes effect.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE server='1'
ORDER BY important DESC, rand();
```

This assumes that there are multiple types with the same importance.